# React native scroll Text horizontal

Tags: android, react-native

How to create a text scrolling bar in react native? 
Like that of news scroll. Is it possible without using Animation library?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a user-controlled scroll you have a component for this - `ScrollView`

Here's a link to the official documentation - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html

If you want it to scroll automatically you need you use ScrollView with the Animated library or use ScrollView's scrollTo function.